# Timer issue in jbpm embedded in grails

Tags: grails, jbpm

I followed this link
http://www.intelligrape.com/blog/2010/05/14/embedding-jbpm-4-3-in-a-grails-1-2-2-application/

to embed jbpm in my project.

The issue is timer is not triggered. I found that jobexecutor is not started.

Can anyone help me to make it work?

Iam using jbpm4.4 and grails 1.3.5

Thanks in advance

rams

Answer (score 0):

By default job execution is disabled in JBPM configuration.
Check your *jbpm.cfg.xml* file and uncomment this line:

```
<import resource="jbpm.jobexecutor.cfg.xml" />
```

If there is no *jbpm.cfg.xml* in a grails environment check if you jBPM configuration cantains these lines:

```
<process-engine-context>
   <job-executor />
</process-engine-context>
```